# Should project_id be a part of the payload of the notification or data message?

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working on pushing notifications using FCM with HTTP Legacy protocol. Currently, my payload looks something like this:

```
var textNotificationTest = new
                        {
                            to = deviceToken,
                            priority = "high",
                            notification = new
                            {
                                title = notificationTitle,
                                text = notificationContent,
                                content_available = true,
                                sound = "enabled",
                                badge = notificationBadge,
                                id = notificationId
                            },
                            data = new
                            {
                                title = notificationTitle,
                                text = notificationContent,
                                notificationId = notificationId
                            },
                            project_id = "Some project id",
                        };
```

I am not sure if the project_id is required or not.

According to https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#credentials the Project_id is used in requests to the FCM v1 HTTP endpoint.

Does anyone know if the project id needs to be included as part of payload or there is any other place where we can keep it?

I have the authorisation key and the sender id as part of my request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not used in the payload. It's to be used in the *endpoint*. From the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1), the endpoint format:

> POST https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/myproject-b5ae1/messages:send

`myproject-b5ae1` being the project ID.

Comment: If I still want to keep using the legacy Http protocol then where would the project_id be required? I currently am weighing if I want to migrate to HTTP V1 or not, so I want to stick to legacy http then is it mandatory to have the project id be added somewhere?

Comment: @Damon - from the same docs you mentioned (with emphasis): A unique identifier for your Firebase project, *used in requests to the FCM v1 HTTP endpoint*. It's only needed (server-side wise) when using v1.

Comment: Thanks a lot  @AL. I did take it out from my legacy HTTP protocol version.